# Salvar dados em varias tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro e gostaria de uma ajuda de voces para poder salvar os dados em varias tabelas.

Meu cadastro e composto pelos seguintes campos.

```
Nome do Paciente
Nome do Doutor
Tipo de Serviço
Data de Entrada
Estagio
```

Agora assim esta minha tabela do banco de dados:

`id_paciente
 nome_do_paciente
 nome_do_doutor`

Esses dados serão salvos na tabela paciente e preciso do id desse registro para dar sequência.

`id_servico
 tipo_servico
 data_servico
 id_paciente`

Esses dados serão salvos na tabela serviço e preciso também do id desse registro.

`id_estagio
 id_servico
 data_estagio
 tipo_estagio`

Esses dados serão salvos na tabela estagio e preciso também do id desse registro.

`Abre_Conexao();`

```
if (@mysql_query(INSERT INTO cad_paciente VALUES (NULL, $nome_paciente, $nome_doutor))) {

    if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){
        echo "Registro efetuado com sucesso<br />";
    }

}
```

Já vi fucionando dessa maneira abaixo mais quero acrescentar a esse padrão acima pois meu codigo esta todo nele

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO paciente VALUES ('NULL, $nome_paciente, $nome_doutor')";
mysql_query( $query1 );

$id_paciente = mysql_insert_id();

$query2 = "INSERT INTO servico VALUES ('NULL, tipo_servico, data_servico,{$id_paciente})";
mysql_query( $query2 );

$id_servico = mysql_insert_id();

$query3 = "INSERT INTO estagio VALUES ('NULL, {$id_servico}, data_estagio, tipo_estagio')";
mysql_query( $query3 );
```

Comment: E o php entra onde nessa história?

Comment: Editei a pergunta informando melhor o que estou precisando

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o PHP tem uma função nativa (mysql_insert_id) para retornar o ID gerado.

Tenta dar uma olhada nessa documentação:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php

ex.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

if (!$link) {

die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}

mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

faça assim:

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO cad_paciente VALUES (NULL, "$nome_paciente", "$nome_doutor"))) {

    if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){
        echo "Registro efetuado com sucesso<br />";
    }

}
```

entretanto, depois que estudar um pouco mais de PHP e de MySQL e estiver com tudo funcionando, procure outro método de inserir os dados ou pelo menos validar os dados antes de fazer coisas como essa, pois esse método permite um tipo de ataque chamado SQL Injection.

Comment: Nelson eu quero e dar continuidade salvando os registros para que eu faça apenas uma tela de cadastro e nao varias telas cada uma para cada tabela, quero fazer apenas uma tela e nela inserir todos os dados e ao enviar para fazer o insert ele ja distribuir os dados automaticamente

Comment: $query1 = "INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES ('test')";
mysql_query( $query1 );

$id = mysql_insert_id();

$query2 = "INSERT INTO test_2 (test_id, value) VALUES ({$id}, 'test')";
mysql_query( $query2 );

Comment: Tipo esse que postei no comentario

Comment: @CristianoCardosoSilva olha... o melhor é elaborar isso em outra pergunta. Pq assim no comentário ficou muito confuso. Nas resposta eu mostrei como inserir dados em uma tabela. Agora, a lógica a seguir fica por sua conta.

Comment: Tem com verificar a pergunta novamente

Comment: e qual o problema ? use o     if(mysql_affected_rows() para cada query

Comment: Não dei conta de montar, ele salva apenas o primeiro

Comment: retire as aspas simples e tente novamente